# Display MM/DD value only for date type field when record get saved

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have specific requirement like:

First `Financial_Start_Date__c` is a field of type `Date` (`MM/DD/YYYY`) on the `Contract` object, and I want to display `MM/DD` after record is saved.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. The expectation is you have tried to solve your problem and are running into specific issues with your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

With a formula, you can do some formatting. Here are the [functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) you would need:

> **Function:** `TEXT`
>     **Description:** Converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field into text anywhere formulas are used. Also, converts picklist values to text in approval rules, approval step rules, workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, auto-response rules, validation rules, formula fields, field updates, and custom buttons and links.
>     **Use:** `TEXT(value)` and replace `value` with the field or expression you want to convert to text format. Avoid using any special characters besides a decimal point (period) or minus sign (dash) in this function.
>
> **Function:** `MONTH`
>     **Description:** Returns the month, a number between 1 (January) and 12 (December) in number format of a given date.
>     **Use:** `MONTH(date)` and replace `date` with the field or expression for the date containing the month you want returned.
>
> **Function:** `DAY`
>     **Description:** Returns a day of the month in the form of a number between 1 and 31.
>     **Use:** `DAY(date)` and replace `date` with a date field or value such as `TODAY()`.
>
> **Function:** `LPAD`
>     **Description**: Inserts characters you specify to the left-side of a text string.
>     **Use:** `LPAD(text, padded_length[, pad_string])` and replace the variables:
>
> - `text` is the field or expression you want to insert characters to the left of.
> - `padded_length` is the number of total characters in the text that will be returned.
> - `pad_string` is the character or characters that should be inserted. `pad_string` is optional and defaults to a blank space.
>
>   If the value in text is longer than pad_string, text is truncated to the size of padded_length.

You also need the [concatenation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#Concatenate) operator:

> **Description:** Connects two or more strings.
>     **Use:** `string1&string2` and replace each string with merge fields, expressions, or other values.
>     **Example:** `"Expense-" & Trip_Name__c & "-" & ExpenseNum__c` This formula displays the text “Expense-” followed by trip name and the expense number. This is a text formula field that uses an expense number custom field.

Just a simple example of how to get the zero padded day should get you started:

```
LPAD(TEXT(DAY(Datefield__c)), 2, "0")
```

Comment: There's also an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BouXAAS) for a native data type.

Comment: Dunno if I see the value in it. Not many people do, apparently (6 votes).

Comment: I bet more people would find it useful if they found out about it. Also, a Month/Year data type.